# What is the geometric interpretation of the constant c/||n||? (vectors)

Tags: geometry, vectors

[See part (e) of the attache image]

Part (e) of the question attached: Find the geometric interpretation of the constant c/||n||, when both sides of the cartesian equation x•n=c is divided by the norm ||n|| of the vector n.

I understand how they obtained the equivalent Cartesian equation but am struggling to understand the geometric interpretation of the constant (on the RHS).

[Question Part (e)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaeNp.jpg)

Comment: Please take the time to enter key parts of your question’s context as text instead of pasting a picture of it. Images are neither searchable nor accessible to people using screen readers.

Comment: Hint: what is the minimal distance between a point on the plane and origin?

Comment: @achillehui The minimal distance between a point on the plane and origin is in the direction of the normal vector. However, I can not see how this is helpful in this case.

Comment: If you compute the number for your plane $x\cdot n = c$, you will find the minimal distance equals to your constant.

Answer (score -1):

Hopefully you get to see this before your class, but try multiplying the dot product so you get to a Cartesian description of a line. From that, it should be easy to see what the constant means.